# segue performed before the UIAlertController in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, ibaction, unwind-segue

I have just coded a signup page in which if user does not enter text in any of the uitextfield then it should receive an error message (UIAlert) ; else (if user enter text in all uitextfield) signup page will present for Firebase Authentication.

in my code, user will direct to sign-in page only if authentication successfully complete else it should remain in signup page with alert message.

Problem - my code is able to produce alert message but same time it is taking user to sign-in page automatically even when there is an error. which means it is performing a segue that takes user to sign-in page i.e. segue unwinding irrespective of alert message.

can anyone help me why this may be happening?

```
 @IBAction func registerPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    if nameText.text!.isEmpty || genderText.text!.isEmpty || countryText.text!.isEmpty || yourSchool.text!.isEmpty || yourClass.text!.isEmpty {

        print("Please fill all fields") //my code is printing this error

        //alert message popup - my code is ble to produce this alert but same it is performing segue and taking user to signin page
        //ideally, i want user to be in signup page unless all criteria meet

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please fill all fields", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
        print("Okay")
        }))

        let alertWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        alertWindow.rootViewController = UIViewController()
        alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert
        alertWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
        alertWindow.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

    else {

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: yourEmail.text!, password: yourPassword.text!) { (user, error) in

                    if error != nil {

                        ///print errror message

                        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
                            print("Okay")
                        }))

                        let alertWindow = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
                        alertWindow.rootViewController = UIViewController()
                        alertWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelAlert + 1;
                        alertWindow.makeKeyAndVisible()
                        alertWindow.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                    }

                    else {

                        print("You have successfully signed up")

                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "JoinUs2SignPage", sender: self)

                        //updating user information
                        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
                        let usertype: String = "Student"
                        self.ref.child("users").child(userID).setValue(["usertype": usertype ,"username": self.nameText.text!, "usergender": self.genderText.text!, "usercountry": self.countryText.text!, "userschool": self.yourSchool.text!, "userclass": self.yourClass.text!,])
                        }
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

From this bit of code it doesn't really look like anything is wrong. However, you should block the UI while `Auth.auth().createUser(...)` is running. Otherwise there's a chance that you call `registerPressed` with everything correct, but then delete the text from a label and call it again before the callback. That way you have an alert and *then* the segue is called.

You're also doing something quite crazy with the way that you're presenting your alerts. Instead of creating a new window, adding to it a view controller and all that jazz, just call `self.present(alertController, animated: true)`. E.g.

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please fill all fields", preferredStyle: .alert)
alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
    print("Okay")
}))

self.present(alertController, animated: true)
```

Comment: You are absolutely correct but if I dont use the crazy part of my code it would give me an error i.e. Attempt to present UIAlertController whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
so it avoid the error i had to use jazzy things .. no choice

Comment: That should be a red flag for you. If the view controller doing this stuff is not in the window hierarchy then you have a serious problem with your setup. Your code here isn't "jazzy", it's a hack that's hiding a bigger problem.

Comment: you were absolutely correct .. I was doing a silly mistake that caused everything. I created a segue directly on IBAction button so whenever I pressed the button it was performing the segue irrespective of anything .. I deleted that segue and created new one in which I connected sign-up view to sign-in UI view and it solved everything

Comment: You're welcome :) If my answer helped you please mark it. I need those sweet sweet reputation points :p

Answer (score 0):

Remove the segue and push to destination view controller programmatically.

```
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(destinationVC, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was doing a silly mistake where I created the segue directly on IBAction and hence whenever I was pressing the button it was performing the segue irrespective UIAlerts. my updated code is below :

```
   @IBAction func registerPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    if nameText.text!.isEmpty || genderText.text!.isEmpty || countryText.text!.isEmpty || yourSchool.text!.isEmpty || yourClass.text!.isEmpty {

        //alert message popup

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Please fill all fields", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
        print("Okay")
        }))

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)


    }

    else {

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: yourEmail.text!, password: yourPassword.text!) { (user, error) in

                    if error != nil {

                        ///print errror message

                        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in
                            print("Okay")
                        }))

                        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                    }

                    else {

                        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Congratulation", message: "You have successfully signed up", preferredStyle: .alert)
                        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Get Started", style: .default, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) in

                            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "back2SignPage", sender: self)
                        }))

                        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

                        //updating user information
                        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
                        let usertype: String = "Student"
                        self.ref.child("users").child(userID).setValue(["usertype": usertype ,"username": self.nameText.text!, "usergender": self.genderText.text!, "usercountry": self.countryText.text!, "userschool": self.yourSchool.text!, "userclass": self.yourClass.text!,])
                        }
            }
        }

}
```